# Queuing disciplines are per-interface, what happen with interfaces using same device?

Tags: linux, networking, embedded, tc

I have read about queuing disciplines here http://lartc.org/.

I understand that for instance band 0 of pfifo policy is prioritized over band 2 within same qdisc, but what happen when i have ppp0 and ppp1 interfaces using same ADSL line? I mean which ATM frame is prioritized when there is outgoing traffic in both interfaces, band 0 of ppp0 or band 0 of ppp1?